# Group by count with two columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, group-by, arel

I would like to group on two different columns and get the count as a nested hash.

```
User.group('role').count => gives me {"admin" => 10, "user" => 15}
```

How do i write a query to get result like this(grouping by role and gender)

```
{"admin" => {"male" => 2, "female" => 3}, "user" => {"male" => 4, "female" => 4}}
```

Comment: Role is admin and user .. and what is the field for male female ?

Comment: @PankhuriKaushik: gender

Comment: I guess you ll have to iterate again. First User.group_by {¦t¦ t.role}.each.collect.{¦ u¦ {u[0] => u[1].group("gender"). Count}} . Can't be sure of exact syntax. But approach should be like this.